# How can I reduce whitespace in Python plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, geopandas

I am plotting 2 shapefiles (converted to geopandas dataframe) using this. But there is too much whitespace. How can I reduce it to fill the box more with the map? The `xlim` and `ylim` doesn't seem to have any impact

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 8))
polydatx.plot(ax = ax, column = 'Elev_Avg', cmap='OrRd', scheme='quantiles')
segdatx.plot(ax = ax)
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_ylim(47, 47.3)
plt.axis('equal');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in calling

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

after setting the new `ylim`.

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html):

> `axis('equal')`
>   changes limits of x or y axis so that equal increments of x and y have the same length; a circle is circular.:
>
> `axis('scaled')`
>   achieves the same result by changing the dimensions of the plot box instead of the axis data limits.

In your case I would adjust the figure size to some rectangle, not a square and use `axis('scaled')`.